# Remove mailman from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, uninstall, mailman

I use webmin for configuring the server and also for running the update and upgrade the softwarepackages. It uses first the `apt-get update` and than the `apt-get -y -f upgrade` command.

Yesterday I would try to upgrade the **items (like bind9, etc)**, but suddenly it seemed to stop with upgrading. For some reason it tries to install mailman on my server, but it can't complete it. After more then 15 minutes it is still not installed. So, I aborted the **upgrade/install** and rebooted the server and tried again. But again after waiting a long time, mailman won't get installed at all.

Now I want to remove mailman from my server. But to remove it, I have to complete the install of mailman first, it says, than I can remove it. But neither installing, neither removing seems to work.

I tried it with this command:

```
apt-get remove mailman -y
```

---

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mailman
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 36.2 MB disk space will be freed.
dpkg: error processing package mailman (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mailman
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

And I even tried the command below, but also it won't be removed:

```
apt-get remove --purge mailman -y
```

---

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mailman*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 36.2 MB disk space will be freed.
dpkg: error processing package mailman (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mailman
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Can someone help me to remove mailman, please? Or, if that's impossible, how can I skip the **mailman-upgrade/install**, so that other upgrades can be done.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: `you should reinstall it before attempting a removal`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on my virtualmin servers by running:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mailman start
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```